# Is Android GRALLOC needed?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Gralloc (from Android porting guide)

Allocates memory for graphics buffers. **See the If you are using version 1.1 or later of the hardware composer, this HAL is no longer needed.**

If GRALLOC is not needed, how are the buffers allocated? am i reading it wrong?

could anyone clarify this please?